# VBA to SQL error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am using a SQL server database to hold data.

The data is entered onto the excel sheet, and a macro then runs to insert the data into a SQL database.

One of the cells on the excel sheet has a value called 'ONE HUNDRED'. When I run the macro, I get an error saying 'Incorrect syntax near ONE HUNDRED'

Could someone please advise why I am getting this error?

Code is below.

```
Sub server()

Dim sConnString As String


    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=xx;Initial Catalog=xx;Integrated Security=SSPI;": MsgBox "Connection Successful"
    objMyConn.Open

    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn

    Dim val1 As String, val2 As String, val3 As String, val4 As String, val5 As String

    val1 = Range("D9").Value
    val2 = Range("D10").Value
    val3 = Range("D11").Value
    val4 = Range("D12").Value
    val5 = Range("D13").Value

    Dim item1 As String
    item1 = "INSERT INTO [xx].[dbo].[server]("
    item1 = item1 & "  [server_name],[ip_address], [phys_location], [phys_or_virt], [it_contact] "

    item1 = item1 & "  )Values("
    item1 = item1 & "  '" & val1 & "', '" & val2 & "', '" & val3 & "', '" & val4 & "', '" & val5 & "'"

    objMyConn.Execute item1


End Sub
```

Comment: and the cell is val5, right?

Comment: You have a missing `")"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parenthesis at the end of `item1`

```
item1 = item1 & "  '" & val1 & "', '" & val2 & "', '" & val3 & "', '" & val4 & "', '" & val5 & "')"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try closing parenthesis at the end sql string